# the fragment in viewpager not destroyed when the memory clear

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

The mainActivity recovered, the fragment cannot be seen but the lifecycle is absolutely loading well.

```
     mContainer.setAdapter(new FragmentPagerAdapter(activity.getSupportFragmentManager()) {
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hey and welcome to SO! You can help others help you by providing code examples that clearly illustrate what you have already tried and where you got stuck. This greatly increases the chance of a user being able to solve your particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this in a fragment, you must pass a childFragmentManager to the pager adapter.

```
mContainer.setAdapter(new FragmentPagerAdapter(***getChildFragmentManager()***) {
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }
});
```

Comment: it just in activity, not a fragment.  when it go background after a long time, activity is reCreated, but the fragment in viewpager not reCreated, it can see in the source       code,  the fragment lifecycle the go well, but the view of the fragment created not be seen, it just the problem